# How to show back button in ion nav bar?

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Hi i am using a template having both tab and side menu. in that when i navigate from one page to other i need to show both side menu button and back button i am using the below template

```
<ion-side-menus>

<ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="nav-title-slide-ios7 bar-positive">
           <ion-nav-bar type="bar-positive"
                 back-button-type="button-icon"
                 back-button-icon="ion-ios7-arrow-back"
                 animation="nav-title-slide-ios7"
            >


    <ion-nav-view name="main"></ion-nav-view>
    <ion-footer-bar align-title="left" class="bar-calm">

        <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive" animation="slide-bottom-top">

            <ion-tab icon="ion-homepage" ui-sref="main.home">
                <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>

            <ion-tab  icon="ion-notification" ui-sref="main.notification">
                <ion-nav-view name="notification-tab"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>

            <ion-tab  icon="ion-searching" ui-sref="main.search">
                <ion-nav-view name="search-tab"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>

            <ion-tab  icon="ion-preference" ui-sref="main.preference">
                <ion-nav-view name="preference-tab"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>

        </ion-tabs>



    </ion-footer-bar>
</ion-pane>

<ion-side-menu side="left" animation="slide-left-right">

    <ion-content has-header="false">
        <ul class="list">
            <li><a ui-sref="main.test1" class="item horses" ng-click="toggleMenu()">Horses</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="main.test2" class="item races" ng-click="toggleMenu()">Races</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="main.twst3" class="item news" ng-click="toggleMenu()">News</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="main.t3tw" class="item clinic" ng-click="toggleMenu()">Clinic</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="main.homffe" class="item live" ng-click="toggleMenu()">Live</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="main.ters" class="item chats" ng-click="toggleMenu()">Chat</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="main.ters" class="item update" ng-click="toggleMenu()">Update</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="entry" class="item">Log Out</a>
        </ul>
    </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
```

it only showing the side menu button back button is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are having the same problem as this guy [Ionic side menu not present on each view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571452/ionic-side-menu-not-present-on-each-view/31573705#31573705)

If you look at the answer it tries to place the side menu button and the back button in the same place but can only show one at a time, you will either need to change where the buttons are so they dont overlap using some css directives instead of the javascript ones, or just add another button somewhere else on the page. Hope this helps!